# How do you print the response in a Grails / Spock test instead of: org.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockHttpServletResponse@62c0fcae

Tags: grails, println, groovy-console

I'm writing Spock tests for my Grails backend. I'm quite new to testing in Grails, and I'm trying to view the response to my mock request.

When I write println(response) I see this in the standard output: `org.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockHttpServletResponse@62c0fcae`

instead of the actual response. Is there anyway to view the contents of this mock http response instead of what is currently being printed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use Groovy's [dump](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#dump()) method:

> Generates a detailed dump string of an object showing its class, hashCode and fields.

```
println(response.dump())
```

**My example:**

```
def response = new GrailsMockHttpServletResponse()
println(response.dump())
```

**Output:**

```
<org.grails.plugins.testing.GrailsMockHttpServletResponse@6a79c292 outputStreamAccessAllowed=true writerAccessAllowed=true characterEncoding=ISO-8859-1 charset=false content= outputStream=org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse$ResponseServletOutputStream@21a947fe writer=null contentLength=0 contentType=null bufferSize=4096 committed=false locale=en_US cookies=[] headers=[:] status=200 errorMessage=null forwardedUrl=null includedUrls=[]>
```

Comment: or you could use `response.text`, `response.status`, etc from the [inherited methods](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.1/api/org/grails/plugins/testing/GrailsMockHttpServletResponse.html)